# Navigation Marker

Tags: android, api, maps

I'm making a Navigation based application for Android using API. I have successfully added Google Maps to my app. But now I want to add navigation marker (arrow like symbol) same as we see in official Navigation app of Google. I searched allot but didnt found anything. So can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [link](http://hmkcode.com/adding-a-marker-to-google-android-map-v2-running-on-android-2-3-3/) to a good read about this.
Try this:

```
GoogleMap map;
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Hello world"));
```

Comment: While the link might provide the answer to the question, it is not recommend to place a link only answer. Always make sure you quote the relevant pieces in your answer, so it'll still be helpfull if the site cannot be accessed anymore. For more information, see [answer]